# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

i have gone through the code and tried new things over and over and can't seem to get rid of this error. i am writing a program where i scan a file as input and it goes through and finds average, max, and min. but i have had aproblem towards the end of the code where i have to give a grade for each score and then count up how many of each grades there are. it compiles fine but when i go to run it the java.langNoClassDefFoundError: keeps coming up please help if you can.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


class Exam
{
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
{
int A;
int B;
int C;
int D;
int F;
// Greets user and prompts to enter name of the file containing there grades.
  System.out.println("***Welcome to the Exam Statistics Program!!***");   
  Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Please enter a filename:");
  String filename = cin.next();


// Scanner built for new file and puts grades into an array.  
Scanner file = new Scanner(new FileReader(filename));
  int g;
    g=file.nextInt();
    int [] grades = new int[g];
    for(int i=0; i<grades.length; i++)
    {
      grades[i] = file.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Minimum Score:  " + getMinValue(grades));
    System.out.println("Maximum Score:  " + getMaxValue(grades));
    System.out.println("Average Score:  " + Average(grades));
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(" ");

    System.out.println("A:  " +A);
    System.out.println("B:  " +B);
    System.out.println("C:  " +C);
    System.out.println("D:  " +D);
    System.out.println("F:  " +F);
    System.out.println("The grade count is: "+ g);
}


// Calculates the average of the array and returns the variable containing that values.
static double Average( int [] grades)
{
    double sum=0;
    double x;
    for(int i=0; i<grades.length; i++)
        sum += (double)grades[i];
    if(grades.length==0) return 0;
      x = sum/grades.length;
    return x;

}
// Calculates the lowest grade in the file.
public static int getMinValue(int[] grades)
{  
  int minValue = grades[0];  
  for(int i=1;i<grades.length;i++)
  {

      if(grades[i] < minValue)
      {
        minValue = grades[i];  
      }  
      }return minValue;
}
// Calculates the highest grade in the file.
public static int getMaxValue(int[] grades)
{  
    int maxValue = grades[0];  
    for(int i=1;i < grades.length;i++)
    {  
        if(grades[i] > maxValue)
        {  
          maxValue = grades[i];  
        }  
    }  return maxValue;  
}  

// Adds up the total number of letter grades you have in the file.
public static int countA(int[] grades) //throws IOException
{
  int A=0;
  for(int i=1; i<grades.length;i++)
        {
            if(grades[i]>89||grades[i]<=100)
            {
              A = A++;
            }
        }
  return A;
}
public static int countB(int[] grades)
{
  int B=0;
  for(int i=1; i<grades.length;i++)
        {
            if(grades[i]>79||grades[i]<=89)
            {
              B = B++;
            }
        }
  return B;

}
public static int countC(int[] grades)
{
  int C = 0;
  for(int i=1; i<grades.length;i++)
        {
            if(grades[i]>69||grades[i]<=79)
            {
              C = C++;
            }
        }
  return C;
}
public static int countD(int[] grades)
{
  int D = 0;
  for(int i=1; i<grades.length;i++)
        {
            if(grades[i]>59||grades[i]<=69)
            {
              D = D++;
            }
        }
  return D;
}
public static int countF(int[] grades)
{
  int F = 0;
  for(int i=1; i<grades.length;i++)
        {
            if(grades[i]<=59)
            {
              F = F++;
            }
  }
  return F;
 }
 }
```

Comment: Show us the stacktrace with the NoClassDefFoundException

Comment: Which is the class that it is unable to find?  Please provide the stack trace

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Exam2
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Exam2
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)

Comment: Is your source file named Exam2.java?

Comment: how are you compiling and running your code.what is Exam2.java

Comment: yes the source file is Exam2.java, and i am compiling it thruogh puTty with javac Exam2.java

Answer (score 3):

Your stacktrace shows error  `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Exam2`.

But your class is named `Exam`. So change your filename to `Exam.java` from `Exam2.java`

Answer (score 1):

Here you have created a Java file with name Exam2.java. As per Java's File naming convention you must give your file name same as the class name which contains Main Method. But as per your Main Method's class it is Exam, So I would suggest you to change it to Exam2 instead of class Exam.